# questions about dynamic and static in various scenarios(Java)

Tags: java, memory, dynamic, static

I have been confused for the words "dynamic" and "static" for a while. As I know, in different scenarios, they may have different meanings. Anyone can help me make it clear. I hope the explanations will be focused in Java. Thanks in advance!

Scenario 1: what does that mean when they are applied to data structures，like arrays? People usually regard linkedlist as dynamic and  arrays as static. Why? And sometimes arrays could be either static(in stack) or dynamic(in heap). Why this happens?

Scenario 2: what does that mean when they are applied to memory? Why stack is static and heap is dynamic?

Scenario 3: what does that mean when they are applied to dynamic programming? is there such a thing called static programming?

Answer (score 0):

Scenario 1:
Arrays in java cannot grow: If they are created they keep their size until they die. A LinkedList on the other hand can add elements on the fly without much effort it's size isn't fixed. If you add an element to a ArrayList and the underlying array is full the ArrayList actually copies all the element in a new array with the correct size.

Example:

```
int[] ints = new int[4]; //size is known

int[] ints2 = new int[] {1, 2, 3}; //size is known
```

The reason for this is, that the runtime can allocate one block of memory for the array.

Scenario 2:
Assumption: You mean the call stack.
The heap of a program is changed during runtime. Your java program creates objects on the fly and deletes them again - this is not known ahead of time. The java compiler nor the VM have knowledge when in the future an object is created. 
The stack on the other hand is somewhat determined by the compiler: The compiler generates the code for calling a method and he knows how much memory he will use to call a particular method. Worth to mention is a recursive method: The compiler generates the code to calling the recursive method again but he doesn't know how many times. So the stack is not strictly static its just that the change to the stack (how many items will be pushed and poped from it) are known ahead of time but the actual size and data is only known at runtime.

Scenario 3:
Dynamic programming is a Technic you use to solve some algorithmic problems. See the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). And no, there is no such thing as static programming.

Answer (score 0):

See when you're working on java, everything is object and all the objects are dynamically allocated during the runtime.

Lets look at your scenario :

Scenario 1: what does that mean when they are applied to data structures，like arrays? People usually regard linkedlist as dynamic and arrays as static. Why? And sometimes arrays could be either static(in stack) or dynamic(in heap). Why this happens?

See in other languages while creating array you'll write something like this:

```
int array[10];// allocates space for 10 integers in memory.
```

See the above is static allocation because we're explicitly mentioning the size and this size is getting allocated for array during **compilation**.

If you want to allocate the memory dynamically we can use functions like malloc, calloc, etc.. And whenever we create linked lists we allocate the memory for them using those functions.

But again in java, arrays are objects. And we create them using **new** keyword. So it means they're dynamically allocated.

Now Scenario 2: what does that mean when they are applied to memory? Why stack is static and heap is dynamic?

I guess I have already answered this in the answer of scenario 1.

Now Scenario 3: what does that mean when they are applied to dynamic programming? is there such a thing called static programming?

There's no such static programming . Instead there are static variables ( in C, C++ etc), static members (in java). To know what static members are see this link [static members](http://blog.sanaulla.info/2008/06/24/static-members-static-methods-and-static-variables/) and finally **dynamic programming** is a technique used to solve complex problems and algorithms.

HTH :)